# Convert Notepad++ syntax highlighting file to vim (or does anyone have a q/kdb+ vim syntax highlight file?)

Tags: vim, notepad++, vim-syntax-highlighting, kdb

I have a syntax highlighting file for the q/kdb+ language and I'd like to convert it to a vim compatible file so my q code won't look any more ugly than usual.

Are there utilities available to automatically convert notepad++ xml syntax highlighting files to vi versions? I had a look around but I couldn't find anything.

Alternatively does anyone have a vim q syntax highlighting file?

Answer (score 6):

a q/kdb+ vim syntax highlight files:
https://github.com/simongarland/vim

Answer (score 4):

The answer to both questions is no (I don't know of any converters and I don't have a q syntax highlighting file), but the Notepad++ syntax highlighting XML format looks extremely simple.  I don't have the 'Q' one to hand, but I had a look at one of the ones from the [website](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files) and the translation looks pretty trivial.  In that case, you could do most of the work with:

```
" Remove all the lines that aren't lists of keywords
" (there doesn't seem to be anything much more complicated
" than that in the definition file)
:g!/<Keywords name=/d
" Convert the lines (fairly poor XML parsing here!)
:%s/\s*<Keywords name="\([^"]\+\)">\([[:alpha:]_ ]\{-}\)<\/Keywords>/syn keyword \1 \2/
```

This generates lots of lines that look like:

```
syn keyword Words1 case then do while
```

You'll have to tweak the syntax class (Words1 in this case) to be something that will be highlighted in Vim (or syn-link it to something that will be highlighted in Vim).

You could probably then deal with the symbols with a regexp, but it might be easier to just do them by hand, so convert:

```
<Keywords name="Operators">- ! &quot; # $ &amp; * , . ; ? @ \ ^ { | } ~ + &lt; = &gt;</Keywords>
```

into:

```
syn match Operators /\<[-!"#$&*,.;?@\\^{|}~+<=>]/
```

(this is `\<` to mark a word boundary, followed by a character class `[..]` with all the symbols in it).

You would then just need to add:

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif
```

at the start and:

```
let b:current_syntax = "q"
```

at the end.

Of course, this doesn't get you all the way, but hopefully it will give you a lot of what you need to get the syntax file that you want.  There is plenty of help available in:

```
:help syntax
```

and by looking at the examples in the syntax directory of the runtime folder.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! That should make the process of making a vim file easier, it doesn't look hugely complicated.. I'm just lazy.